# React Native expo updating a cloned repo

Tags: react-native, expo

I created a react native project with the expo and uploaded it to GitHub. I then cloned the project on my other computer, but now it has fewer files because of the .gitignore file.
My question is how can I update my cloned project to install back those files. such as the node_modules and all its other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, just do a yarn to install all the packages

Comment: What does this mean, "yarn to install all the packages"? Please specify the actual command.